# android is my application still running?

Tags: java, android

i have this thread which run as a service:

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(timeInterval);
                results = sendGetMessage();
                b.putString("results", results);
                receiver.send(2, b);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            results = e.toString();
        }
    this.stop();
    }
```

i want to write a simple function which will check if my application is still running (in order to replace the everlasting while(ture) i've written).
something like: while(isMyAppRunning).
my problem now that even when i'm closing the app, the service keep on running..
can someone please be kind and give me a code example?

Comment: PS you should never call `stop()`

Comment: why not ? how else should i stop the service ?

Comment: This is `Thread.stop()`, right? just remove it. The thread stops when `run()` ends. `stop()` forcibly halts the thread which has been deprecated since like Java 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the other way around. Make a boolean flag `running` in this `Thread` subclass. Start it as `true` and expose a `shutdown()` method which sets it to `false`. Call this method from your `Activity`'s `onPause()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `context.stopService(Intent service);` to stop the service when you no longer need it. You can perform all the upkeep for stopping the thread and so on in the services `onDestroy()` method.

You could also have some `boolean` that you would set to false when the application exists, although I would prefer the first solution myself.

Comment: my service is needed as long as the application is running.
as you said i want to make a boolean that will flag if the application exist or not, i just don't know how to do it.. :)

Comment: You can have a static boolean (for example in a class that extends Application) and set that to false.

Comment: if i have a class which extends Application class, will it be the first to load whenever i run the application?

Comment: Yes, you just need to point the manifest file to that application class.